# Chrome browser randomly hangs on start from chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I have several tests that are automated using selenium/python.
Tests are run through teamcity, in xfvb drive where you installed Ubuntu 14.04.
all 28 tests, and when they run, I see a process that runs Chrome (using the command ps auvvx | grep chrome | grep -v grep):

```
teamcity 31660  2.5  0.0 139000  8368 ?        Sl   13:10   0:00 /opt/vendors/chromedriver/webdriver --port=50695 --log-path=chromedriverEnBundlesTests.log
teamcity 31680 27.3  0.2 625396 70948 ?        Rl   13:10   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-hang-monitor --disable-infobars --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --lang=en --load-component-extension=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.EnML8k/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12388 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.65DCDh --v=1 --verbose --–-single-process data:,
teamcity 31693  1.0  0.0 335680 26132 ?        S    13:10   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-logging --log-level=0 --v=1 --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.65DCDh
teamcity 31696  0.0  0.0  26192  2068 ?        S    13:10   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
teamcity 31699  0.0  0.0 335680  8448 ?        S    13:10   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-logging --log-level=0 --v=1 --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.65DCDh
teamcity 31749  2.5  0.0 706404 31408 ?        Sl   13:10   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-logging --log-level=0 --test-type=webdriver --v=1 --primordial-pipe-token=1DE74651242181EC5B45C60E6057984B --lang=en-US --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.65DCDh --extension-process --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-webrtc-hw-encoding --disable-gpu-compositing --service-request-channel-token=1DE74651242181EC5B45C60E6057984B --renderer-client-id=2 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
teamcity 31772 14.5  0.1 734440 46176 ?        Sl   13:10   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-logging --log-level=0 --test-type=webdriver --v=1 --primordial-pipe-token=29BAB961D66EB1226D9E5A0151BC00FD --lang=en-US --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.65DCDh --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-webrtc-hw-encoding --disable-gpu-compositing --service-request-channel-token=29BAB961D66EB1226D9E5A0151BC00FD --renderer-client-id=4 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
```

but sometimes (it happens on a random test) chrome does not start. does not start - means that chrome processes have started, but the chrome window does not appear on the screen (I'm watching to xvfb via VNCviewer). however, although the chrome processes are started, but they looks quite strange:

```
teamcity 30480 0.0 0.0 135880 7956 ? Sl 09:24 0:00 /opt/vendors/chromedriver/webdriver --port=34227 --log-path=chromedriverBundlesTests.log
teamcity 30485 0.0 0.1 558912 53480 ? Sl 09:24 0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-hang-monitor --disable-infobars --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --lang=en --load-component-extension=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.xt55yX/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12290 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-agent=CustomUserAgent --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.pFyqzd --v=1 --verbose data:, 
teamcity 30496 0.0 0.0 335680 26128 ? S 09:24 0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-logging --log-level=0 --v=1 --user-agent=CustomUserAgent --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.pFyqzd
teamcity 30500 0.0 0.0 26192 2064 ? S 09:24 0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
teamcity 30503 0.0 0.0 335680 8432 ? S 09:24 0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-logging --log-level=0 --v=1 --user-agent=CustomUserAgent --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.pFyqzd
teamcity 30535 0.0 0.0 343876 10328 ? Sl 09:24 0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-logging --log-level=0 --test-type=webdriver --v=1 --primordial-pipe-token=059B5A32F7C1B61E6E6C194E4D3A0DC8 --lang=en-US --user-agent=CustomUserAgent --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.pFyqzd --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --disable-webrtc-hw-encoding --disable-gpu-compositing --service-request-channel-token=059B5A32F7C1B61E6E6C194E4D3A0DC8 --renderer-client-id=3 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
teamcity 30537 0.2 0.0 558668 14976 ? S 09:24 0:04 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-hang-monitor --disable-infobars --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --lang=en --load-component-extension=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.xt55yX/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12290 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-agent=CustomUserAgent --user-data-dir=/var/tainted/build-agent/temp/buildTmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.pFyqzd --v=1 --verbose data:,
```

and in this state, the chrome may remain hours or days.
below is an example of a test, how I run Chrome from chromedriver:

```
def setUp(self):
    os.environ["CHROME_LOG_FILE"] = 'DeTeasersTests.log'
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--verbose')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--v=1')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
        service_log_path = "chromedriverDeTeasersTests.log"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/vendors/chromedriver/webdriver', chrome_options=chrome_options,
                                       service_log_path=service_log_path)
    elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options,
                                       service_log_path='chromedriver.log')
    self.base_url = BASE_DE_URL
    self.driver.get(self.base_url)
```

and tail of test:

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.quit()
```

---

please help figure out what the error is? at the moment tests run hangs in 2/3 of cases. on Windows everything works flawlessly.

p.s. I'm sorry if I'm wrong to write in English.
my native language - Russian, and I was looking for a solution in the Russian-speaking Internet, but found nothing.
p.p.s. I have tried many ways to this problem:
play with the parameters of chrome (--no-sandbox, --single-process, --process-per-site, --disable-gpu, etc.);
write and analize log of chrome and chromedriver - but the logs are no exceptions or errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

has been solved in
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1699

tl;dr

I added the definition of this environment variable in the script, like this:

```
    def setUp(self):
        os.environ["DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"] = '/dev/null'
        chrome_options = Options()
```

And it really helped.
Build was launched about 20 times, and all were successfully passed, although before that, chrome hung on 3-5 launch for sure.